# Obtaining a $3$-dimensional simple random walk from a $d$-dimensional simple random walk with $d>3$.

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Suppose $S_n$ is a $d$-dimensional random walk with $d>3$. Let $T_n=(S_n^{(1)},S_n^{(2)},S_n^{(3)})$, that is, we obtain $T_n$ by looking only at the first three coordinates of $S_n$. It is clear $T_n$ isn't always a simple random walk. Define a random variable $N$ by $N(0)=0$ and $$N(k+1)=\inf\{m>N(k):T_m\neq T_{N(k)}\}$$

The claim is that $T_{N(k)}$ is a simple three dimensional random walk. This is from Durret's "*Probability: Theory and Examples*", and is claimed without proof. Could someone provide one?

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of a $d$ dimensional simple random walk.  Is it a process that has increments which are iid densities in $\mathbb{R}^d$, or at each point in time, is a direction along an axis chosen and movement occurs in that direction?

Comment: @muaddib Take a sequence of i.i.d. samples $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with $P(X_i=\pm e_j)=\dfrac 1{2d}$. Then $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is a simple random walk.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I am stuck on the same problem. Could you share how you prove the uniform distribution over the steps? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the proof for a simple random walk, which can be generalized further. Hopefully it's clear that $T_{N(k)}$ as a function of $k$ changes exactly one coordinate for each $k$ and moreover $|T_{N(k+1)}-T_{N(k)}|_\infty=1$. More importantly, $T_{N(k+1)}|$ is a Markov process. So it suffices to verify that each step is uniformly random: the probability of a particular step is 1/6. This can be proven in a multitude of ways. One way is to just condition on $N(k+1)-N(k)$, and realize that the distribution of $T_{N(k+1)}$ is independent of this difference. Then show that $T_{N(k+1)}$ can be rewritten as $T_{N(k)}$ plus the argmin of the waiting times of jumps in the first 3 coordinates, each of which has the same distribution (but are not independent!). It's useful to remark that $T_{N(k)}$ like the bigger $d$-dimensional random walk is also invariant under permutations of its coordinates.

Comment: Is there a more hands on elementary argument? You lost me at "Markov process."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: A Markov process in this context is just that the random walk that you get has transition probabilities which are independent of it's prior history, except the last position. In other words, $P(T_{N(k)} | T_{N(k-1)},...,T_{N(0)} ) = P(T_{N(k)} | T_{N(k-1)})$. You might be able to show that the transitions are uniform but to really be a simple random walk, each step must be independent of the last.

Comment: I see where you're getting at. By uniform you mean that each direction has equal probability, I presume. At any rate, it wouldn't hurt to spell out some details. The point is to show that if I let say $X_n=T_{N(n)}-T_{N(n-1)}$ then these are i.i.d. uniform?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: exactly.

Comment: At any rate, it wouldn't hurt to spell out some details. The point is to show that if I let say $X_n=T_{N(n)}-T_{N(n-1)}$ then these are i.i.d. uniform on the unit vectors?

Comment: Could you confirm the above?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Correct in addition to showing that these differences are independent, for all $n$.